# does std::is_same has an impact on the performance of the code?

Tags: c++, templates, performance-testing

Does `is_same` has any impact on the code performance? I am using it multiple times in my code to check whether i have to use `std::less` or `std::greater` and depending on them i have to retrieve specific values. Is my test sufficient to prove that std::is_same does not really impact the performance of the code in my case?

The code is much more complex than that and I have to use templates. I tried as much as i can to mimic the places where `is_same` is used.

I compiled and ran the code with `-O3` compiler option.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono> 

using namespace std::chrono; 
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int returnVal(T compare) {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
    if(std::is_same<T,std::greater<int>>::value) {
        return std::min(v[0], v[1], compare);
    } else {
        return std::min(v[2], v[3], compare);
    }
}

int returnValNoTemplate(bool b) {
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
    if(b == true) {
        return std::min(v[0], v[1]);
    } else {
        return std::min(v[2], v[3]);
    }
}


int main()
{   
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
      for(int i  = 0; i < 100000;++i) {
        int x = returnVal(std::greater<int>());
      }
    
      auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start); 
      cout <<"is_same duration:" <<  duration.count() << "\n" << endl; 
    
      auto start1 = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
      for(int i  = 0; i < 100000;++i) {
       int y = returnValNoTemplate(true);
      }
      auto stop1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto duration1 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop1 - start1); 
      cout <<"No template duration:" <<  duration1.count() << "\n" << endl; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

**R1:** is_same duration:4052 No template duration:4041

**R2:** is_same duration:3954 No template duration:3950

**R3:** is_same duration:3963 No template duration:3973

**R4:** is_same duration:4008 No template duration:4048

**R5:** is_same duration:3948 No template duration:3998

**R6:** is_same duration:4130 No template duration:4036

**R7:** is_same duration:3932 No template duration:3948

**R8:** is_same duration:4183 No template duration:4088

**R9:** is_same duration:4731 No template duration:5062

**R10:** is_same duration:4018 No template duration:4887

---

#Swaping tests#

**R1:** No template duration:5729 is_same duration:5474

**R2:** No template duration:3988 is_same duration:4039

**R3:** No template duration:3996 is_same duration:4114

**R4:** No template duration:4063 is_same duration:4068

**R5:** No template duration:3979 is_same duration:4096

**R6:** No template duration:4159 is_same duration:4020

**R7:** No template duration:3990 is_same duration:4086

**R8:** No template duration:4001 is_same duration:4055

**R9:** No template duration:4048 is_same duration:4088

**R10:**No template duration:4070 is_same duration:4017

Comment: I'll be surprised if it does. I've always assumed those checks happen at compile time, and functions are generated to handle each type

Comment: When testing performance it is extremely important that you test a build of your code with compiler optimizations turned *on* (aka a "release build"). The default for most compilers is to do an unoptimized (aka "debug") build. Unoptimized builds are notoriously slow and often in places that optimized builds eliminate completely. Don't benchmark debug builds, it's pointless and doesn't reflect real performance of final release builds at all.

Comment: In theory the template version could perform better, since `std::is_same` is resolved at compile time.  Since you're passing a constant value to the other version I would expect the compiler to generate the same assembly for both in this case though.  I suspect the difference would be close to undetectable either way though.

Comment: `std::is_same` is a compile time constant, as though you had written `true` or `false` in place of it. The performance characteristics will therefore be identical to using a literal `true` or `false` value -- the compiler is certainly going to eliminate the conditional and the false branch (both gcc and clang do this even with `-O0`).

Comment: Swapping the order of the tests might change the results too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

std:is_same is a compile time check it is implemented with two different template footprints.  One with 1 Type and 1 with 2 Types.

```
std::is_same<T, T> //If the compiler resolves to this it is the same type;
std::is_same<T, U> //If the compiler resolves to this it is 2 types;
```

The implementation returns a type that then has a conversion to bool which resolves to true or false generating one pathway for the code to follow.

Comment: @SergeyA I attempted to clarify some more.